# WPF Xaml Grid - can I number columns starting from the end (e.g. Grid.Column="-1")

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I have a WPF grid with many rows and columns, written with Xaml.
In the grid, I want to place an element in the *last (rightmost)* column.
The problem is, if I need to add another column,  the all items on the right move left by one.
Is there a way to specify in (preferred Xaml only) the index from the end, similar to indexing in some languages mylist[-1] to denote the last item.

Comment: there is no such way

Comment: on the second thought, try [CalcBinding](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/calcbinding/info)

Answer (score 2):

If you set `Grid.Column` to a number higher than the number of columns, it will put the element in the last column. So you could set `Grid.Column` to something like `Int32.MaxValue` (or any number that you can guarantee will always be greater than the number of columns) and that element will always be in the last column no matter how many new columns you add.

Comment: Thanks, This works, and solves my problem. However, this will not  work if  you would like one-before-the-last column. e.g: Grid.Column = "-2".

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it in pure XAML, but you can do it by binding the `Grid.Column` property to the number of grid columns and using a converter to add the offset from the end:

```
public class OffsetConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (int)value + Int32.Parse(parameter?.ToString());
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }
}
```

Which you then use like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:OffsetConverter x:Key="OffsetConverter" />
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="Col 0" Grid.Column="0" />
    <TextBlock Text="Col 1" Grid.Column="1" />
    <TextBlock Text="Col -2" Grid.Column="{Binding Path=ColumnDefinitions.Count, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Grid}, Converter={StaticResource OffsetConverter}, ConverterParameter=-2}" />
    <TextBlock Text="Col -1" Grid.Column="{Binding Path=ColumnDefinitions.Count, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Grid}, Converter={StaticResource OffsetConverter}, ConverterParameter=-1}" />
</Grid>
```

Result:

[image]

Only problem with this specific implementation is that it uses CommandParameter to pass in the offset, which means it has to be a constant hard-coded into the XAML. If you need to bind it to another property then use a MultiConverter instead and pass it in as the second parameter.

While this does work, the fact you need to do it suggests you may have a more fundamental, underlying architectural problem. Even if you're not doing full-blown MVVM, the data you bind your front-end to should be readying that data
for easy consumption by the view. In this case, that layer should probably be aware of the number of columns itself and also be able to calculate the column number of each element that you're displaying. The fact that you're being forced to calculate all this after-the-fact, and on the other side of the view, suggests you might want to re-think your architecture (assuming, of course, you're in full control of it and also have time to do it).